# Generate XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to generate the XML file from the PHP array.
Everything seems working quite well, but I cannot remove the parent node.

This is how my array looks like:

[image: This is how my array looks like:]

And this is the generated XML file

[image]

As you can see I have some "items" inside the parent node named "item".

I just want to know, how I can remove the parent node named "item" and leave just structure like:

[image]

My PHP code:

```
    function array_to_xml( $data, $xml_data ) {
        foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
            if( is_numeric($key) ){
                $key = 'item';
            }
            if( is_array($value) ) {
                $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            } else {
                $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
            }
         }
    }

    $xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');

    array_to_xml($newArrayXml,$xml_data);

    //saving generated xml file; 
    $result = $xml_data->asXML('list.xml')
```

Comment: I would suggest that the parent node `item` should probably be something like `items`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need to use the XML importer and that imported do not understand the structure like I have it now (with parent node item).

Comment: Can you please post a decent, formatted version of `var_dump( $newArrayXml );`? Images of code are always awful, never helpful, and always hurt your chance of getting someone else to look at your problem. Additionally, your `array_to_xml()` function looks like it handles recursion, correct? If yes, then stop passing in nested arrays or whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the above code using the following array, it output what you are looking for:

```
$newArrayXml = array(
 2410687 => array('id' => 2410687),
 2440673 => array('id' => 2440673),
 2415709 => array('id' => 2415709),
 2445675 => array('id' => 2445675)
);

// var_dump($newArrayXml);exit;

function array_to_xml( $data, $xml_data ) {
 foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
  if( is_numeric($key) ){
   $key = 'item';
  }
  if( is_array($value) ) {
   $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
   array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
  } else {
   $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
  }
 }
}

$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');

array_to_xml($newArrayXml,$xml_data);

//saving generated xml file;
$result = $xml_data->asXML('list.xml');
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<item><id>2410687</id></item>
<item><id>2440673</id></item>
<item><id>2415709</id></item>
<item><id>2445675</id></item>
</data>
```

Perhaps the issue is with your array. It shows `array(1)` in your photo, which would imply you have an extra array:

```
$newArrayXml = array(array(
 2410687 => array('id' => 2410687),
 2440673 => array('id' => 2440673),
 2415709 => array('id' => 2415709),
 2445675 => array('id' => 2445675)
));
```

This generates the output that you did not want.

Comment: yes I understand that all my items are in additional array. But how can I avoid that?

Comment: I don't know how the array is generated, but you can call `$newArrayXML = current($newArrayXML);` or `$newArrayXML = array_shift($newArrayXML);` to get rid of the outside array.

Comment: $newArrayXML = current($newArrayXML); - worked perfect. Thank you.